# CUDA 5.5 with Debian Wheezy/Jesse

Tags: installation, debian, compatibility, debian-wheezy, cuda

I'm thinking of installing the recently-released CUDA 5.5 on top of Debian. Questions:

- Is it recommendable to install it on Debian testing (as of Sep 2013, i.e. Jesse), or Debian stable (as of Sep 2013, i.e. wheezy)?
- What special actions, if any, do I need to take to install and use CUDA, say with Eclipse and Nsight, on each of these two distributions?